# How to "reduce" Jenkins Pipeline output path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We were building our solution without any "Pipeline" in Jenkins until recently, so I'm currently in the progress to move our build to multibranch pipelines.

The issue that I'm running into is that we have a lot of structure une our solution(lot of subfolder, and sometimes some big names).

Currently, the jenkins pipeline extract everything in a folder that looks like:

`D:\ws\ght-build_feature_pipelines-TMQ33LB5OQIQ5VXVMFKFDG2HWCD4MUOGEGUWJUOMZ5D2GI42BIQA`

Which is very-long, and now we are reaching the 260 characters limit of `MSBuild`:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2991,5):
>   error MSB3553: Resource file
>   "obj\Release\xx.aaaaaaaaaa.yyy.bbbbbb.dddddddddddddd.yyyyyyy.vvv.dddddddddd.Resources.resources"
>   has an invalid name. The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied
>   to the path
>   "obj\Release\xx.aaaaaaaaaa.yyy.bbbbbb.dddddddddddddd.yyyyyyy.vvv.dddddddddd.Resources.resources".
>   The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   [D:\ws\ght-build_feature_pipelines-TMQ33LB5OQIQ5VXVMFKFDG2HWCD4MUOGEGUWJUOMZ5D2GI42BIQA\Src\bbbbbb\dddddd\dddddddddddddd\yyyyyyy\xx.aaaaaaaaaa.yyy.bbbbbb.dddddddddddddd.yyyyyyy.vvv\xx.aaaaaaaaaa.yyy.bbbbbb.dddddddddddddd.yyyyyyy.vvv.csproj]

We have so much cases where the length is big that it's really a big job to refactor everything, so I'm looking on how to specify to jenkins a smaller path?

Answer (score 5):

What I finally did:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node{
            label 'windows-node'
            customWorkspace "D:\\ws\\${env.BRANCH_NAME}"            
        }
    }
    options{
        skipDefaultCheckout()
    }
...
}
```

And I've a  step that does the checkout. It was easier for me to have a "per-job" behavior, without touching jenkins global settings.

Answer (score 4):

### Update (for any recent Jenkins instances)

Turns out that with recent Jenkins versions `PATH_MAX` seems to be ignored.
The only thing it does: Issue a warning in the Jenkins log when smaller than a certain value, which actually does not matter - as the setting itself will anyways be ignored (as seen on Jenkins 2.249.3). See also: [JENKINS-2111](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-2111)

As far as I can tell - the new setting was introduced in **jenkins-branch-api 2.0.21**:

There's a new property introduced: `MAX_LENGTH`.
This defaults to 32 characters by default.

You can set it the same way like `PATH_MAX`:

As a java property - to ensure that Jenkins will start using the right setting, e.g.:

```
-Djenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.MAX_LENGTH=40
```

or during run-time, using the script console:

```
jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.MAX_LENGTH=40
```

---

### For older Jenkins instances

Actually there's a java property you can set to specify the length of the directory name, e.g.:

```
-Djenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.PATH_MAX=20
```

To make it permanent you have to specify this property in the Jenkins java startup configuration file.

You may also read and write this property using the Jenkins script console for temporary changes or to just give it a try as it takes effect immediately, e.g.

```
println jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.PATH_MAX
jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.PATH_MAX = 20
println jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.PATH_MAX
```

Setting this value to 0 changes the path generation behavior.

For details please check:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34564
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38706

Comment: so this will impact the other jobs on the server?

Comment: It will change the path for all multibranch jobs but leave alone all other jobs (Freestyle and plain Pipeline)

Comment: Ok, just for my understanding, this path will include the base workspace? (Which is D:\ws for us) or only the "generated" part?

Comment: It‘s the generated part. Maybe you should briefly check the links, there are some more hints about this setting in there.

Comment: Joerg, the 2nd one worked, but the first one maybe I didn't understood. I've tried to initialize jenkins like this:
```java -jar jenkins.war -Djenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.PATH_MAX=20```

Is that what I was suppose to do?

Comment: @DiogoNeves: Sorry for the late response, took a while to find the exact settings we're using. Now I can confirm that we use the following on the jenkins command line: `-Djenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.PATH_MAX=20`